# Auto email subject line not updating when list is edited

Tags: sharepoint-online

On my site there are bulletins that get posted each day. When they are posted, Auto Email workflow sends emails to users using the bulletin title as the email subject line. When I edit the bulletin and change the title, in some cases it will not show the updated title in the subject line but still show the previous title.

In my workflow history, I am logging the item title and can see that it is recognizing the updated title but it is not always reflected in the email subject line.

[image]

Does SharePoint cache item titles?